# How to display the images from the array (user controlled traffic lights)

Tags: javascript, arrays, image

```html
<!-- I set the tags here-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- I set the coding language-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
     <!-- The image variables can be seen here-->
    var TrafficLights = new array()
    image[0] = "traffic-light-red.jpg";
    image[1] = "traffic-light-red-amber.jpg";
    image[2] = "traffic-light-green.jpg";
    image[3] = "traffic-light-amber.jpg";

     <!--they are then put into an array-->
    var TrafficLightImages = [image1, image2, image3, image4]

     <!-- I close the script and head tags-->
  </script>
</head>
<!-- I start a body tag-->

<body>
  <!-- Create a button with the button class= "myButton" and name it to say
         "Change the lights!"-->
  <!-- It will also change the image of the traffic light-->
  <button class="myButton" onclick="slideit()">Change the lights!</button>

  <!-- I call the URL of the image and I set its width and length to 120 and 270
<img src="traffic-light-red.jpg" name="slide" width="152" height="320">

<!-- I set the coding language-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
     <!-- I create another variable that makes step=1-->
    var step = 1;
    var i = 0
      <!--Previously this was a do/while loop but I changed as I learnt it was the
            source of my previous problem-->
      <!-- I create a function names slide-->

    function UpdateImage() {
        for (i = 0; i < TrafficLights.length; i++) { <!-- Change this -->

          document.write("<li><img src='" + TrafficLights[i] + "'width="
            150 "    height="
            110 "/>span>" + TrafficLights[i] + "</span><li>");


          //-->
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The lines above are the code. How does one rotate through the different images of traffic lights from an array, display them and only changes the image when you press the button.

If possible, please show a full working script.

Comment: At first image1 doesnt exist, image[1] does

Comment: Off topic but worth mentioning. Your comments are overabundant, they make your code harder to read.

Comment: where is slideit() method??

Answer (score 0):

document.write() only adds HTML to the end of your document.

To change an existing  tag you need to have an event handler that changes the 'src' attribute of the image DOM node.

```
<script>
function changeImage(image_name) {
    var img = document.getElementById("image_id");
    img.src = image_name;
}
</script>

<img src='placeholder.png' id='image_id' />
<input type='button' value='Set Green' onClick='changeImage("traffic-light-green.jpg");' />
<input type='button' value='Set Red' onClick='changeImage("traffic-light-red.jpg");' />
```